# Is importing one Excel spreadsheet into another Excel spreadsheet possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, spreadsheet

Can I import an Excel spreadsheet into another spreadsheet (two separate files) by linking in certain cells from one to show in other cells in a different file?

I'm not sure if I can do this or where I'd go if it possible to make it work. I have no programming background.

Comment: Are you thinking that you want a spreadsheet which is updated when either of the separate files is changed, or is this a one-time thing? You can certainly just copy and paste row/column/cell ranges between worksheets to "import" one into another.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the cell in your 'source' spreadsheet, then do a 'Paste Special' into your target spreadsheet. This will copy the value and leave a link pointing to the original spreadsheet, so changes in the source will be reflected in the target.

Comment: use this if you do not want a file to be dependent of another

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

- Open both workbooks
- Activate the workbook you want automatically updated
- Select a cell you want to link
- Type `=`
- Activate the other workbook
- Select the cell you want to link and hit "enter"
- You will return to the first workbook and the selected cell will
  contain the reference e.g. `=[FirstFile.xls]Sheet1!$A$11`
- Repeat for each cell you want to link
- If you want to, you could include references in formulae, say if
  you wanted half the value, you would do as above then add `/2` to get
  `=[FirstFile.xls]Sheet1!$A$11/2` or maybe multiply the vales of two
  cells e.g.

  ```
  =[FirstFile.xls]Sheet1!$A$11* =[FirstFile.xls]Sheet1!$B$42
  ```

Comment: doesn't this require both sheets to be open? I mean if the formulae is supposed to evaluate properly...

Comment: no, it doesn't necessary the two files opened, but if you change the path or the name of mentioned FirstFile.xls the dependent workbook will warn about it when opened